# export/import data in cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra

I want to export a keyspcae including whole data some thing like we do in mysql from  a single node cassandra cluster and restore it on another single node cluster.

Comment: Why have you asked the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682197/keyspace-schema-import-and-export-cassandra

Comment: If I’m not mistaken, the linked question asks for the schema, not for the data. But I’m no expert in the named technologies, so the instructions might be equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Has explain on the documentation you can do a snapshot or use the tools `sstable2json` and `json2sstable`.

For more information you can do a search on the documentation:
    http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Operations#Backing_up_data

About the snapshot tool: http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/operations/backup_restore

Comment: hello and thanks for your reply,i used sstable command for this i have to convert each columns family data to json that is too time consuming.  
i have four keyspace hotel1,hotel2,hotel3,hotel4 and i want to create hotel1 on other node whith its column family and coresponding data for this i want  export whole keyspace hotel1 including column familes and there data and import on other node , i tried snapshot but it also makes the snapshot for each column family and i am not understanding it properly that how it works   please help me

Comment: any one please help me as soon as possible

Comment: If your servers are sopped you can try to do a `scp root@node1:/var/lib/cassandra/data root@node2:/var/lib/cassandra/data` but I'm not sure that works. About the snapshot, do you have tested http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/operations/backup_restore

Answer (score 0):

Backup/restore and many other things might be done with excellent Priam toolset: https://github.com/Netflix/Priam.
I'd say, the setup process is rather complicated, but anyway it's easier than sstable-to-json conversion on all nodes.