# Keyspace schema import and export in Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra

I have a Cassandra 1.1.2 installation on my system as a single node cluster and have three keyspaces: `hotel`, `student` and `employee`. I want to dump the keyspace schema of `hotel` along with its column family data if possible and restore the dump on other Cassandra cluster. Can any one suggest me in detail that how should I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `sstable2json` and `json2sstable` cassandra tools

Check out Datastax [documentation](http://www.datastax.com/docs/0.7/utilities/sstable2json) on the same and [this](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Operations#Import_.2BAC8_export) too

```
Usage: sstable2json [-f outfile] <sstable> [-k key [-k key [...]]]
Usage: json2sstable -K keyspace -c column_family <json> <sstable>
```

You can always execute cassandra-cli commands in file

```
cassandra-cli -h HOST -p PORT -f fileName
```

You can load all your create statements in to a file and execute this command

To get cli scripts to create keyspaces and column families use following command in cassandra-cli interface

```
show schema
```

But incase you wanna create a cluster of two nodes. You don't need to do all the above. Just starting the other node with different token range and same cluster name would do. Cassandra internally will manage to stream the data and schema informations

Comment: thanks tamil thank you very much i have been facing this problem from 3 days it is a good solution  

i have one thing to ask after geting keyspace and restoring it on other cluster can i copy and paste the keyspace data  that is present in to the data directory

Comment: no you can't do that. Do a `nodetool drain` [incase you want all data even in memory] on the existing one node cluster and proceed with json loader. No other go. nodetool drain will flush all CFs but your current cluster will be inaccessible till this operation finishes.

Comment: Thanks but i did what i have mentioned above and it is working fine will it create any problem if i will not use node drain etc

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. But it is not the recommended way. Hope you are not seeing some inconsistencies. Carefully monitor your cassandra logs.

Comment: Remember to flush your sstables to disk before using sstable2json command:

`nodetool flush keyspace cfname`

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend use `stable2json` and `json2sstable` to load a large amout of data. It uses jackson API to create the dataset and transform it to json format. It implies to load all of the data in memory to create a unique json representation.

It is ok for a few amount of data, now imagine to load a large dataset of more than 40 million of rows, about 25GB of data, these tools simply doesn't work well. I already asked datastax guys about it without clarification.

In case of large datasets, just copy cassandra data files from a cluster to another may solve the problem. In my case I'm was trying to migrate from Cassandra 1.0.6 cluster to a 1.2.1, the data files were not compatible between this versions.

What is the solution?
I'm just writing my own export/import tool to solve this. I hope to post a link for this tool soon.