# What is the fastest way to copy Column family in Cassandra?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cassandra, hector

I want to create copy of Column Family with another name in Cassandra using Hector(or any other client), Is there any fastest way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: To clarify: Given an existing column family containing some amount of data and the name of a new column family, create a column family with the new name with the same schema and data content as the original.  Is that correct?  What about other metadata like number of nodes, policies, etc.?

Comment: Actually I want to Copy all data of one column family to another, Means at end two same copy of one column family created with different name, We can do one way iterating row by row and reading columns and writing to another column families, But I want faster way to do this. Is there any faster way to do this?

Comment: Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682197/keyspace-schema-import-and-export-cassandra/11683309#11683309

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cassandra hadoop integration reads a whole column family to use as input to a map reduce job; it can also output in bulk to a column family. Have a read of the code in the `org.apache.cassandra.hadoop` package to get an idea of what to do.

For the read, it figures out which tokens are on which nodes and then does a [get_range_slice](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API#get_range_slices) using that token range (it splits up the token range into manageable chunks too). For the write it does (or can do if you use the Bulk* classes) a similar thing to the above solutions by constructing an SSTable and then uploading that to cassandra.

I suspect the other answers above using sstable2json would be far and away more efficient, but this would work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sstable2json to read it out, then json2sstable to write it back as your new CF.

Comment: I want to do this programmatically. Have you any example to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

My answer was going to involve iterating row by row which you say you already are doing.  My only improvement over that is to use a KeySlice to get multiple keys, and therefore multiple rows, per request.