# How to fill a Cassandra Column Family from another one's columns?

Tags: hadoop, cassandra

I have always read that Cassandra is good if your application changes frequently and features are added frequently.

That makes sense, since you don't have any fixed schema, you can add columns to rows to suffice your needs, instead of running an ALTER TABLE query which may freeze your database for hours for very large tables.

However I have an hypotetical problem which I'm not able to solve.
Let's say I have:

```
CREATE COLUMN FAMILY Students
    with comparator='CompositeType(UTF8Type,UTF8Type),
    and key_validation_class=UUIDType;
```

Each student has some generic column (you know, meta:username, meta:password, meta:surname, etc), plus each student may follow N courses. This N-N relationship is resolved using denormalization, adding N columns to each Student (course:ID1, course:ID2).

On the other side, I may have a Courses CF, where each row is contains all of the following Students UUIDs.

So I can ask "which courses are followed by XXX" and "which students follow course YYY".

The problem is: what if I didn't create the second column family? Maybe at the time when the application was built, getting the students following a specific course wasn't a requirement.

This is a simple example, but I believe it's quite common. "With Cassandra you plan CFs in terms of queries instead of relationships". I need that query now, while at first it wasn't needed.

Given a table of students with thousands of entries, how would you fill the Courses CF? Is this a job for Hadoop, Pig or Hive (I never touched any of those, just guessing).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the fastest way to copy Column family in Cassandra?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086395/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-copy-column-family-in-cassandra)

Comment: @ChrisGerken: I don't think so.  He's not wanting to copy data; he's wanting to generate new data based on existing data.  This requires different tools.

Comment: Well, the important fact, is that there is a way to do that job pretty fast, in parallel through Pig and that the operation won't DOS the application behind...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pig (which uses the Hadoop integration) is actually perfect for this type of work, because you can not only read but also write data back into Cassandra using CassandraStorage.  It gives you the parallel processing capability to do the job with minimal time and overhead.  Otherwise the alternative is to write something to do the extraction yourself, then write the new CF.

Here is a Pig example that computes averages from a set of data in one CF and outputs them to another:

```
rows = LOAD 'cassandra://HadoopTest/TestInput' USING CassandraStorage() AS (key:bytearray,cols:bag{col:tuple(name:chararray,value)});
columns = FOREACH rows GENERATE flatten(cols) AS (name,value);
grouped = GROUP columns BY name;
vals = FOREACH grouped GENERATE group, columns.value AS values;
avgs = FOREACH vals GENERATE group, 'Pig_Average' AS name, (long)SUM(values.value)/COUNT(values.value) AS average;    
cass_group = GROUP avgs BY group;   
cass_out = FOREACH cass_group GENERATE group, avgs.(name, average);
STORE cass_out INTO 'cassandra://HadoopTest/TestOutput' USING CassandraStorage();
```

Comment: @Sarge: Well, if you call Pig "application code" then I guess so.  I think of it more like a quick scripting tool.

Comment: Well, the obvious answer was "read all the rows, write back to the new table". However I was curious to see Hadoop in action for this kind of work. Also, reading all the rows is not so efficient in Cassandra...

Comment: @rs_atl Yes - that's what I meant. I was distinguishing from a SQL-like UPDATE...SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the existing cassandra file, you would have to unwind the data. Since NOSQL files are unidirectional this could be a very time consuming operation in Cassandra itself. The data would have to be sorted in the opposite order from the first file. Frankly I believe that you would have to go back to the original data that was used to populate the first file and populate this new file from that.