# How should I copy a keyspace within a cluster

Tags: cassandra

I have a keyspace populated with data that was expensive to generate. I want two copies of this data within my cluster. I would like to end up with two keyspaces: lets call them `mydata` and `mydatabackup`, both of which contain identical data (I don't mind if the Cassandra timestamps are different).

Is there an easy way to do this? Closest thing I can find to an answer is to use sstable2json and json2sstable [as suggested in response to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682197/keyspace-schema-import-and-export-cassandra)? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

" Is there a better way?"

All Cassandra data are stored in the data/ folder (check config value **data_file_directories** in **cassandra.yaml**). You may also check the **saved_caches_directory** and **commitlog_directory** config.

Inside the data folder, you'll have

1. One folder per keyspace
2. One folder for system keyspace
3. Some folder for authentication etc..

   Inside each keyspace folder, you'll have
4. *-Data.db files which contain your real data
5. *-Filter.db files
6. *-Index.db files for index
7. ...

To replicate data, you do a **plain copy** of those folders.

In our team, the ops use a crontab to schedule regular backup of Cassandra data this way.

*Note: sometimes, you may miss live data which are still in memory or in memtable and not flushed yet to disk. You can trigger a full compaction before backuping data files. But full compaction may hurt you perf so be careful*

---

Better answer: use the provided tool to take a snapshot of you DB:

http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/operations/backup_restore

Comment: Instead of doing a full compaction, you can just run `nodetool flush` to ensure your memtables are flushed to disk.

Comment: @Richard Indeed. The doc gives a better alternative: nodetool -h <host> -p <port> snapshot <date>

Comment: I did a plain copy of a snapshot and pasted the files into into a new folder (`mydata`) in the casssandra data directory. However, the data is not available from cassandra-cli. This seems to be because the files are named according to the old keyspace - something like `mydata-cf-hf-1-Data.db`. However, if I rename the files to match the new keyspace (e.g., `mydatabackup-cf-hf-1-Data.db`) and run `nodetool repair mydatabackup`. It seems to work. Thanks @doanduyhai

Comment: Forgot to say, I needed to create the new schema for mydatabackup (a duplicate of the `mydata` schema) before running repair.

Comment: The DataStax link is dead.