# How to backup the data in one kespace and restore it to another keyspace in cassandra?

Tags: python, cassandra

I have a cassandra key space in my AWS node. I want to take backup of this key space and restore it to another key space.

**NOTE:** I was bale to take backup and restore to same keyspace. But not into another key space.

I have tried the following tools:
1. nodetool snapshot
2. Some external tools also.

**sstable loader - Can any one helps me in using this may be with an example?**

Also, Please share if any one have some automated script for back and restore snippets.

Thanks

Venkat

Comment: What has this to do with Python?

Comment: There is an answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790904/how-should-i-copy-a-keyspace-within-a-cluster/18793422#18793422 This worked for me.