# import schema in Cassandra 3.11.0

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

**Cassandra schema,**

```
use testscheduler;
create columnfamily TaskSchedule
with column_type = 'Standard'


and comparator = 'CompositeType(DateType,UTF8Type,UTF8Type)'
  and default_validation_class = 'UTF8Type'
  and key_validation_class = 'CompositeType(Int32Type,UTF8Type)'
  and read_repair_chance = 0.2
  and dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.0
  and populate_io_cache_on_flush = false
  and gc_grace = 43200
  and min_compaction_threshold = 4
  and max_compaction_threshold = 32
  and replicate_on_write = true
  and compaction_strategy = 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.LeveledCompactionStrategy'
  and caching = 'KEYS_ONLY'
  and compression_options = null;
```

I tried with "[Keyspace schema import and export in Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682197/keyspace-schema-import-and-export-in-cassandra)" this example , my currunt cassandra version not support "cassandra-cli" command. how to import above mention schema to cassandra-3.11.0. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cassandra-cli` is deprecated, use `cqlsh` instead (your snippet is also in CQL (cassandra query language) which needs cqlsh). You might create your keyspace before trying to create your tables.

```
CREATE KEYSPACE testscheduler WITH replication = {'class':'SimpleStrategy',
   'replication_factor' : 1};
```

There are some good tutorials out there, for example https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cassandra/ and https://academy.datastax.com/.

Comment: already created testscheduler keyspace. `cqlsh:testscheduler> source 'IDEA_WORKSPACE/SPARROW/time-engine/cassandra-migrations/scheduler-02-cf-TaskSchedule.schema'`IDEA_WORKSPACE/SPARROW/time-engine/cassandra-migrations/scheduler-02-cf-TaskSchedule.schema:18:SyntaxException: line 2:2 mismatched input 'with' expecting '(' (create columnfamily TaskSchedule  [with] column_type...)

Answer (score 0):

You should use *create table* instead of *create columnfamily* in correct format

See datastax documentation
http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlCreateTable.html#cqlCreateTable